# A sequence of truncates of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $f$ is measurable and $A>0$ then the truncation $f_{A}$ defined by:

$$f_{A}(x)=\begin{cases}
         f(x)&\text{if $\left | f(x) \right |\leq A$}\\
         A&\text{if $ f(x)> A $}\\
         A&\text{if $f(x)< A $}
        \end{cases}$$

Let $f$ be an $X$ measurable function on $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of truncates of $f$. If $f$ es integrable with respect to $\mu$, then $\int fd\mu =\lim\int f_{n}d\mu $.

Conversely, if $\sup\int\left | f_{n} \right |d\mu<{+}\infty $ then $f$ is integrable.

I think I´ve already prove the first part, I applied Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem,  because que can see that $f_{n+1}\leq f_{n} \leq f, n\in\mathbb{N}$ so $ (f_{n})\leq \left |f \right | $ and $f$ is integrable, so I have to prove that $(f_{n})$ is a sequence of integrable functions which converges almost everywhere to a real-valuated function and I can applied the theorem, right???

The other part is the one which I have problems to prove it, does anybody can help me a little with that??
Thanks!

Comment: There appear to be some typos. If $f_a(x) = A$ when $f(x)>A$ and $f(x)<A$ then $f$ would be constantly $A$. Also, what is the second part you refer to?

Comment: Sorry, I´ll correct the. Is constant in the border, the rest is the part you cares, is like having parts of the complete function. The part of "conversely" @neuguy

Comment: Yes, I gathered that, but what are we supposed to prove? If $\sup\int |f_n|d\mu<+\infty$ then what?

Comment: Oh big mistake! sorry, then $f$ is integrable. @neuguy

Comment: I formatted a bit your post. Still $f_A$ isn't well defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem wants us to define $f_N(x) = f(x)$ if $0 \leq f(x) \leq N$, $f_N(x) = f(x)$ if $-N \leq f(x) \leq 0$ and $f_N(x) = 0$ otherwise.
Then we have that $f_n \to f$ monotonically and so we can apply the monotone convergence theorem to conclude that $\lim_n \int f_n = \int \lim_n f_n = \int f$.  Now if $\sup_n \int |f_n| < \infty$, then clearly $\int |f| < \infty$ since for any bounded monotonic sequence we have that $\sup_n a_n = \lim_n a_n$.

Comment: You mean "want us to define $f_{N}=f(x)$ if $0\leq f(x) \leq N$" right?

Comment: yes, i will edit my answer, thank you.